# How to rotate a cube using its coordinates in python

Tags: python, computer-vision

I want to visualize a cube rotating and I have to do it using its coordinates. I just want know what formula or function I have to apply to all its coordinates
Thank you in advance

## cube coordinates

```py
# coordinates
cube = np.array([
    [0,0,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,0],
    
    [0,0,1],
    [1,0,1],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,1,1],
    [0,0,1],
        
    [1,0,1],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,1,0],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,1,1],
    [0,1,0]
    ])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @Morad ! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it. Share expected output.

Comment: This is a tough one if you don't know where to start, but not hard once you know how. You can do this by multiplying by a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just multiply homogeneous co-ordinate matrix of cube with desired rotation matrix. First I suggest you to google on 3D translation and rotation matrices. Suppose you want to rotate the 3D points P (1,0,0) and Q (2,0,0) around Z axis by angle theta degrees, then the desired python code is as given below:

```
import numpy as np
import math
pointsMatrix=np.array([[1,2],[0,0],[0,0]])
R_z = np.array([[math.cos(theta),    -math.sin(theta),    0],
                    [math.sin(theta),    math.cos(theta),     0],
                    [0,                     0,                      1]
                    ])
rotatedPoints=np.dot(R_z,pointsMatrix)

print("Rotated points \n",rotatedPoints)
```

If you want to rotate around different axis then use rotation matrix accordingly. If above solution helps you,  don't forget to upvote the answer,it will encourage me.